# Memory leak in LeakCanary for Android

Tags: android, leakcanary

Below are the logs I got through Leak Canary. I am new to this and I am not sure what exactly is the issue here. Can you please help me how can I fix the same.

```
├─ android.app.AppOpsManager$3 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 536 B in 1 objects
│    Anonymous subclass of com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsActiveCallback$Stub
│    ↓ AppOpsManager$3.this$0
│                      ~~~~~~
├─ android.app.AppOpsManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 240 B in 10 objects
│    mContext instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ↓ AppOpsManager.mContext
│                    ~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.ContextImpl instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 9.0 kB in 106 objects
│    mAutofillClient instance of com.welldoc.platform.android.ui.insulinpen.
│    TSBPairAndDataSyncActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    mOuterContext instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ContextImpl.mOuterContext == ContextImpl.this: not tied to any particular
│    lifecycle
│    ↓ ContextImpl.mAutofillClient
│                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.welldoc.platform.android.ui.insulinpen.TSBPairAndDataSyncActivity
​  instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.welldoc.
​     platform.android.ui.insulinpen.TSBPairAndDataSyncActivity received
​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 6.3 MB in 8734 objects
​     key = 76dd66e8-d8cb-4330-9a45-bb6600394233
​     watchDurationMillis = 16635
​     retainedDurationMillis = 11635
​     mDsmApplication instance of com.welldoc.platform.android.
​     DiabetesApplication
​     mApplication instance of com.welldoc.platform.android.DiabetesApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

the log means **AppOpsManager** hold the Activity which has been finished. may be your **AppOpsManager** is a static class, so the **AppOpsManager. mContext** not recycled. u can set `mContext=null` when the Activity finish.

Comment: I don't have mContext anywhere in my Activity. Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: the log you give above:  AppOpsManager.mContext, set it null when activity finish.